# Lock and unlock resources with single command

Tags: delphi, locking, mutex, anonymous-function, delphi-xe6

I am working with threads and that's the reason I use mutexes for locking shared resources. The base usage of locking is to put resources within Lock/unlock block.

```
procedure RefreshData;
begin    
   DataLock;
      GetData;
      GetSettings;
      CheckValues;
      ...
   DataUnlock;
end;
```

Because there is always a pair Lock/Unlock I started thinking about simplified lock/unlock approach which would automatical unlock resources when not needed anymore.

So my idea was to introduce new procedure which would take as an input parameter a reference to precedure. This will give me ability to use anonymous method.

Code would be something like:

```
type TBaseProc = reference to procedure;

procedure TMyObject.LockMethod(AMeth: TBaseProc);
begin
  DataLock;
  try
    AMeth;
  finally
    DataUnlock;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.RefreshData;
begin
  MyObject.LockMethod(
   procedure 
   begin
     GetData;
     GetSettings;
     CheckValues;
     ...
   end;
  );

end;
```

Has this approach any sense or is there better or even easier solution to this?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Do you care about performance or not?

Comment: The easiest solution would be if the compiler had native support for  Lock() statement like in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx. Personally I use code templates for lock/unlock pairs.

Comment: @David: Yes I care about performance. Is there any estimation on how much overhead could cause this approach? 
I guess Lock/Unlock pair is still better approach in terms of performance.

Comment: Here is a [`nice approach`](http://blog.barrkel.com/2010/01/one-liner-raii-in-delphi.html) with interfaces.

Comment: In addition to that... just a short question. When nesting Lock/Unlock blocks in same thread like: mtx1.Acquire; mtx1.Acquire; DoSomeStuff; mtx1.release; mtx1.release. As I am aware locking when mutex is already owned by same thread won't occur but how is with release? Which release will unlock resources, the first one or second call? I am not sure but I think I read somewhere that system has internal count so I assume the last Release will really unlock resources. Am I right?

Comment: I would never ever consider using anything other than the plain try finally here. All other options have hidden try/finally which is opaque and all other options incur overhead. You will be forced to perform heap allocation which is a serious perf headache when threading.

Comment: As for you other question, don't ask new questions in comments. Ask a new question. And make it clear what type of mutex you use. Is it a recursive mutex? If so it is the final release that actually releases. No other way would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is far from perfect because you have one lock per entire application, as I understood from your code. It is better when each independent data entity has its own lock. So you would have an abstract class like this:

```
type
  TAbstractData = class
    private
       CriticalSection: TRtlCriticalSection
    public
       constructor Create;
       procedure Lock;
       procedure Unlock;
       destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

Then inherit other classes from this abstract class that implements locking.

```
       constructor TAbstractData.Create;
       begin
         inherited Create;
         InitializeCriticalSection(CriticalSection);
       end;

       procedure TAbstractData.Lock;
       begin
         EntercriticalSection(CriticalSection);
       end;
 
       procedure TAbstractData.Unlock;
       begin
         LeaveSection(CriticalSection);
       end;

       procedure TAbstractData.Destroy; 
       begin
         DeleteCriticalSection(CriticalSection);
         inherited Destroy;
       end;
```

A `CriticalSection` is the most efficient synchronization class implemented in Windows. It is virtually free - consumes almost no system resources unless there is thread contention, and does not invoke expensive context switch when just one thread uses the data.

After I have submitted the answer, I have found a good article on the Internet - http://blog.synopse.info/post/2016/01/09/Safe-locks-for-multi-thread-applications - the author recommends a similar approach.